# how to fix blank page NullInjectorError

Tags: angular, angularfire

`enter code here`after I put 'import {AngularFireDatabase} from '@angular/fire/database';' my page goes blank but there is no error at my visual studio as it can be compiled by ng serve but when I check at google console there is NullInjectorError

here is my code

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import {AngularFireDatabase} from '@angular/fire/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }


save(user: firebase.User) {
this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).update({
   name: user.displayName,
   email: user.email
 });
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the module and initialize it in the app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'my-app-name'), // imports firebase/app needed for everything
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Please check their [Installation and Setup](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md) README.

Comment: thanks man it work . actually I am so puzzled about these angular fire 2 and angular fire  right now still trying to understand

Comment: Sure anytime. Can you please accept the answer if it solved your problem? Thanks!